# Dead kernel when using ray

Tags: jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, spyder, ray, multiple-processes

I tried to use ray for crawling some data.

My original code before using ray is as below, and works well.

```
def download(n):

    #download nth data

    return downloaded_data
```

I use ray in reference to ray tutorial, and this makes my kernel dead:

```
@ray.remote
def download(n):
    #download nth data
    return downloaded_data

ray.init(num_cpus = 4)
total_data = ray.get([download.remote(x) for x in range(4000)])
```

I tried the code through jupyter and spyder, but in both cases kernel died.

I do not think the reason is memory lack. It does not use so much memory.

What are the possible causes?